# setInterval, why is it that the timer stops only when clearInterval function is above the setInterval function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, setinterval, clearinterval

My timer only stops when clearInterval is defined below the setInterval function. Any explanation would be highly appreciated. Thank you

[image]

Comment: Too much code is missing to answer the question.

Comment: you can't stop a not started timer

Comment: _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)._

Answer (score 0):

setInterval() actually starts a timer where the specified method/routine is executed after the specified interval has elapsed.

clearInterval() on the other hand is used to reset th etimer started by a previous call to setInterval()

Therefore, it is logical to make a call to clearInterval() after setInterval(). Also, clearInterval() requires as an argument, the id of the timer to be stopped which is returned by setInterval(). So you cannot call clearInterval() before setInterval() as you won't have the id of the timer to be cleared.